# Pyautogui TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyautogui

I'm trying to use `locateCenterOnScreen()` function of PyAutoGUI, however it raises :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\windows\Desktop\asd.py", line 3, in <module>
    buttonx, buttony = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('who.jpg')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My code is:

```
import pyautogui

buttonx, buttony = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('who.jpg')
pyautogui.doubleClick(buttonx,buttony)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure "who.jpg" actually exists.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I did. It exist also I put the full path of that picture too. Still same problem.

Comment: *shrug* PyAutoGUI doesn't agree.

Comment: Have you considered using a lossless image format instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I already tried it with other pictures aswell. What you mean 'lossless' ?

Comment: I mean a format that doesn't introduce artifacts or distortion, such as GIF or PNG at maximum quality.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried PNG still same issue. It just does not make any sense pictures are here and it raises error.

Comment: Don't convert the JPEG to PNG, recapture the image. The JPEG would already be distorted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Even if I capture the picture as PNG and my problem solved, what if I need to locate a jpg? Still not a clear solution..

Comment: If a lossy format doesn't work then that would be something to bring up with the PyAutoGUI developers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation of Pyautogui [here](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions), the method locateCenterOnScreen returns None when it can't find the image on your screen.

Note that you are looking for 2 results from this method, but None is just one result (since the method normally returns two, this seems like bad design to me -- it should raise an exception instead, or at least return a tuple with two None objects).

Look at the following example, which is basically what is happening to you:

```
>>> foo,bar = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The simplest and most Pythonic way of addressing this in my opinion would be simply to try and catch it:

```
try:
    buttonx,buttony = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('who.jpg')
except TypeError:
    """ Do something to handle the fact that the image was not found"""
```

EDIT:
To answer your question raised in the comments, there seems to be a misunderstanding with how this library works, or what it finds on the screen. You give the library a representation of what it needs to find via some image. It works far better when that image is lossless, because then it's an exact, pixel-by-pixel representation. The library then searches your computer screen for the actual thing represented by the image provided. It does not, as you raised concerns, find jpegs or pngs. It finds the actual rendered object. So, if you take a screen shot of the icon for your web browser on your desktop, it will find the actual icon from that screenshot and click on it, but only if it's visible. If it's behind other windows or something, it won't find it. It doesn't search the screen for the icon file, but the rendering of the icon itself. So, for instance, if you provided the actual .ico file to the library, it would not be able to find that icon if it was covered by another window, even though that icon is *technically* on your desktop, because it's not currently rendered.

Comment: I have to locate that picture's location, if I catch the error I'll not be able to locate that. This is not a solution for me it's basically an error catching.

Comment: It is exactly error catching. The picture is not found on your screen, so the library returns None. Your question was not "why is the image not found on my screen" it was "why is this error here"? And I answered that perfectly.

Comment: But the pictures are here. My goal is locating the picture's locations, if it raises error then there is no point I'm writing this script.

Comment: Since I can't comment on your post, I'll answer your latest question here, you aren't looking for a png or a jpeg on your screen. You're looking for the real thing. the png is just a representation of what is on your screen.

Comment: Then you very poorly expressed your goal in your question. I would recommend following Ignacio's advice in your comments and capture the image in a lossless format and try to find it. The library is clearly telling you that your screen does not contain the image you specified.

Comment: There are 15 pictures on my screen and I tried ALL of them one by one, and you are telling me these pictures are not on my screen. Don't know how to answer.

Comment: No, you are fundamentally not understanding what the library is doing. The library is not searching your screen for image files. That is not possible. You are providing it with a representation of what it needs to find on your screen. For instance, if I took a screenshot of the stack overflow tab right now, it would find the actual stack overflow tab in my browser. If I took a screenshot of the stack overflow tab, left that screenshot open in some image viewer, and had the library locate the image, that doesn't mean it's looking for a png or a jpg.

Comment: It's like if I gave you a picture of my shoe and told you to search the floor for it. you are not trying to find a picture of my shoe, but the actual shoe. It is the same here, except the library requires an exact representation of it -- and jpeg is not exact. If I gave you a blurry photo of my shoe, and had a lot of shoes that were similar, you might fail to find the right shoe. You must take a screenshot (lossless) of something currently displayed on your screen, and the library will find it.

Comment: I just try to locate a picture's location then double-click on it. You confused me more right now lol.

Comment: This library does not locate pictures. It uses pictures to locate the actual thing. So, if I am trying to open Chromium browser from my desktop, I would take a screenshot of the chromium browser icon and provide that to the library (in png, not jpg, preferably), and then the library would find the location of the real icon on my desktop, not an image.

Comment: I understand now. Please write your comments in your answer and I'll accept it. Let me know when you edit.

Comment: Also write your answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156019/pyautogui-locatecenteronscreen-returns-none-instead-of-coordinates/37040311#37040311 with details. I'll give you the bounty award since you deserved it much.

Comment: Done. I would update your question as well, to be less about the error and more about why you're getting it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156019/pyautogui-locatecenteronscreen-returns-none-instead-of-coordinates/37040311#37040311<-------  write a good detailed answer to this question so I could give you the bounty 150 points.

Answer (score 0):

To **SIMPLIFY** things - a **locateCenterOnScreen()** method should return the center (x,y) coordinates of an image as you called 'who.jpg' ONLY IF IT EXISTS ON THE SCREEN. Otherwise, if the 'who.jpg' image is not found on the screen - THE METHOD SHOULD RETURN 'NONE'.

You can not assign a 'NONE' value to (x,y) coordinates because you get a single value ('NONE') and two variables that are waiting to receive some value. This why you get a "TypeError".

Try to use an Exception, which is an event that may occur during the execution of a program -> for example a TypeError. Try to predict even other events that may occur during execution and you will be good to go with your task!

FOR YOUR CONVENIENCE TRY THE FOLLOWING CODE :

```
try:
    buttonx, buttony = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('who.jpg')
    pyautogui.click(buttonx, buttony)
except TypeError:
    print("A TypeError has been occured!")
```

Answer (score 0):

if instead of x,y you just use one variable x,y would be on [0], and [1]
so it would be something like

```
location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(path)
```

then if not found it would return

```
location = None
```

else would be

```
location[0] = x and location[1] = y
```

Answer (score -4):

If size of your image is 1920x1080, the image calls take about 1 or 2 seconds.

Therefore, try the code below.

> > import pyautogui
> >     import time
> >
> > time.sleep(2)
> >
> > buttonx, buttony = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('who.jpg')
> >     pyautogui.doubleClick(buttonx,buttony)

You will be able to solve your difficulties.