# pyautogui is not finding the image on my screen while using the `locateCenterOnScreen` command

Tags: python, macos, automation, ui-automation, pyautogui

So, I'm playing with `pyautogui` automation python library and trying to find the axis (x, y) of a picture on my screen.

Following the [official documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), we have the following command, which supposedly discovers the axis of the picture on the screen.

```rb
>>> pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('looksLikeThis.png') # returns center x and y
(898, 423)
```

However, it is not finding the image on my screen

1. Here is a simple code that this error is already happening:

```rb
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

pyautogui.moveTo(0, 0, duration=0)
# pyautogui.click(x=650, y=850, clicks=1, interval=0, button='left', duration=1) # Chrome
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("resources/chrome.png")
pyautogui.click(x=x, y=y, clicks=1, interval=0, button='left', duration=1)
```

2. Here is the image I'm searching:

‣ https://i.imgur.com/pSbaUlL.png

3. Here is my screen (MacOS):

‣ https://i.imgur.com/6W6Aic0.png

4. Here is the error:

```
>>> pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("resources/chrome.png")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 204, in locateCenterOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 447, in locateCenterOnScreen
    coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 405, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 383, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 371, in _locateAll_pillow
    raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image.')
pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 174, in wrapper
    raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException
```

Comment: In my case it's working I'm not using **opencv**, it's not working with the image you've provided I think it will only work if you use exact image in your image there's white background also to make detection easy you can use **opencv** with **pyautogui** and can use `confidence` parameter in `locateCenterOnScreen`.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I tried to use the `confidence` parameter, but it says: `NotImplementedError: The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.`. I tried to instal it via `pip3 install opencv-python` and looks like it was a success, it returned `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.9.0.80)`, `Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in /Users/victorcosta/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.26.4)`. Still, `confidence` doesn't work

Comment: The `NotImplementedError` error remains.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156019/pyautogui-locatecenteronscreen-returns-none-instead-of-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of [`pyautogui`](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) in [`pyscreeze`](https://pypi.org/project/PyScreeze/) it detects **`cv2`** like [this](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/eeca245a135cf171c163b3691300138518efa64e/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L25) and then it sets the **`locateAll`** based on [**`_useOpenCV`**](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/eeca245a135cf171c163b3691300138518efa64e/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L764)

Based on provided information please check if you've installed the [`opencv-python`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) package properly
try to import it like they've done in source code.

This is how my code looks using **opencv**:

```py
import os
import pyautogui


pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

pyautogui.moveTo(0, 0, duration=0)
# pyautogui.click(x=650, y=850, clicks=1, interval=0, button='left', duration=1) # Chrome
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_path = os.path.join(dirname, "resources/chrome.png")

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img_path, confidence=0.4)
pyautogui.click(x=x, y=y, clicks=1, interval=0, button='left', duration=1)
```

In above code I've used `0.4` as `confidence` value because the image you've provided it does not match with my chrome icon I've provided my chrome Icon [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XG7k.png).

**Note:** If it's still not working then you've to get exact image of chrome Icon from your device using some **Snipping Tool**.